# org.apache.jasper.jasperexception unable to compile class for jsp

Tags: java

i am getting this error when i run my jsp file, please help me to find out this.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 619 in the jsp file: /bbb_api.jsp
The type Date is ambiguous
616:                String starttime = recording.getElementsByTagName("startTime").item(0).getTextContent();
617:                try{
618:                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
619:                    Date resultdate = new Date(Long.parseLong(starttime));
620:                    starttime = sdf.format(resultdate);
621:                }catch(Exception e){
622: 

Stacktrace:
                                                                                        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.37 logs.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
```

Comment: i already import the namespace <%@page import="java.util.*"%>

Answer (score 1):

import date from jva.util.Date in the page imports of that JSP

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date" %>
```

or use

fully qualified name of Date class like `java.util.Date`

```
 java.util.Date resultdate = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(starttime));
```

Ambiguous between  sql package Date and util Date class

Answer (score 0):

i think u imported both java.util.Date and javax.sql.Date.

try to remove javax.sql.Date from import statement.